# Angular 2: Delete object in Array

Tags: arrays, angular, delete-row, array-splice

I want to delete an object in an array when that object's ID is equal to the ID of the object getting compared. Currently, it only removes the first object in the array

```js
if(this.selectedProducts.length > 0){
      for(let x of this.selectedProducts){
          if(prod._id === x._id){
              this.selectedProducts.splice(x,1);   //this is the part where I 'delete' the object
              this.appended = false;
          }else{
              this.appended = true;
          }
      }
      if (this.appended) {
          this.selectedProducts.push(prod);
      }
  }else{
      this.selectedProducts.push(prod);                
  }
  this.selectEvent.emit(this.selectedProducts);
}
```

Comment: may be your id comes as one or somehting. I dont see anything related to angular

Comment: Event emitter is angular though @AniruddhaDas

Comment: If `selectedProducts` were a dictionary that whole operation could just be `selectedProducts[prod._id] = prod`

Comment: Do not use `for ... of` for it won't give you the `index` which you want to use at `Array.splice`. try with `for ... in` or `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.selectedProducts.splice(x,1);
```

The first parameter to `splice` must be the index, not the object.

If you're using `for...of`, you can't get the index easily. So you should use a regular `for` loop instead. With some additional simplifications, your code would look like this:

```
for (let i = this.selectedProducts.length - 1; i >= 0; this.selectedProducts.length; i--) {
  if (prod._id === this.selectProducts[i]._id) {
      this.selectedProducts.splice(i, 1);   //this is the part where I 'delete' the object
  }
}
this.selectedProducts.push(prod);
```

It's highly likely that using `filter` would be better anyway:

```
this.selectedProducts = this.selectedProducts.filter(x => prod._id !== x._id).concat(prod);
```